# Calculate this sum $\sum_{x=1}^{{n}/{4}} \frac{1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I calculate this sum
$$\sum_{x=1}^{{n}/{4}} \frac{1}{x}$$
for $n$ an odd integer?

**Added later:** For example, WolframAlpha outputs `4 - Pi/2 - Log[8]` for `HarmonicNumber[1/4]`, what are the steps that produce that? Can they be generalized for any odd number?

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then why would it be divisible by $4$?

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow Why should it be divisible by 4?

Comment: Because otherwise, it's not an integer.

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow Then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual definition of the Harmonic numbers is:
$$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$$
For example, $H_1=1$, $H_2=1+\frac12$,$H_3=1+\frac12+\frac13$, etc. However, this definition is only valid when $n$ is an integer.

When $n$ is not an integer, we use the alternate definition:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+n}\right)$$
For example, $H_2=\left(\frac11-\frac13\right)+\left(\frac12-\frac14\right)+\left(\frac13-\frac15\right)+\left(\frac14-\frac16\right)+\dotsb=1+\frac12$, because everything other than $1$ and $\frac12$ cancels out. The great thing about *this* definition is that it works even when $n$ is not an integer!

You want to find:
$$H_{1/4}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1/4}\right)\approx0.34976\dots$$
in closed form. This sum is usually done using techniques learned in calculus! However, there is a more elementary way of summing this.

(First, we need to know a few things:

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k-1}=1-\frac13+\frac15-\dotsb=\frac\pi4$

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k=1-\frac12+\frac13-\dotsb=\ln2$

If you've never seen these sums before, just trust me.)

Now:
\begin{align}
H_{1/4}=&\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1/4}\right)\\
=&\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac4{4k}+\frac{-4}{4k+1}\right)\\
=&\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{0}{4k}+\frac{-2}{4k+1}+\frac{0}{4k+2}+\frac{2}{4k+3}\right)+\\
&\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{2}{4k}+\frac{-2}{4k+1}+\frac{2}{4k+2}+\frac{-2}{4k+3}\right)+\\
&\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{2}{4k}+\frac{0}{4k+1}+\frac{-2}{4k+2}+\frac{0}{4k+3}\right)
\end{align}
(You'll see why I split it up like that in a moment. To verify that they *are* equal, just add up the columns.)

The first sum is $-\frac25+\frac27-\frac29+\frac2{11}+\dotsb=-2(1-\frac13+\frac15-\dotsb)+2-\frac23=-\frac\pi2+\frac43.$

The second sum is $\frac24-\frac25+\frac26-\frac27+\dotsb=-2(1-\frac12+\frac13-\dotsb)+2-\frac22+\frac23=-2\ln2+\frac53.$

The third sum is $\frac24-\frac26+\frac28-\frac2{10}+\dotsb=\frac12-\frac13+\frac14-\frac15+\dotsb=\\-(1-\frac12+\frac13-\dotsb)+1=-\ln2+1.$

Add them all up and you get $H_{1/4}=4-\frac\pi2-3\ln2$.

Comment: (That's equal to what Wolfram Alpha got, because $3\ln2=\ln2^3=\ln8$.)

Comment: Thank you. Can you generalize this method that you used for $1 \over 4$ for an arbitrary $(2n\pm 1)\over 4$?

Comment: Well, a similar calculation shows that $H_{3/4}=\frac43+\frac\pi2-3\ln2$. From then on, just use the fact that $H_n=H_{n-1}+\frac1n$.

Comment: Do you know if there is a simple form to express only the rational part of $H_n$, that is 4, 4/3, and so on, without pi/2 and 4/3?

Comment: Well, that would be $\overline{H}_{(4n+1)/4}=4+\frac45+\dotsb+\frac4{4n+1}$ and $\overline{H}_{(4n-1)/4}=\frac43+\frac47+\dotsb+\frac4{4n-1}$, which probably can't be simplified. (I'm writing $\overline{H}_n$ to mean the "rational part.")

Comment: P.S. Another way to evaluate $H_{1/4}$ is to expand $4-(1-i)\ln(1+i)-(2)\ln(2)-(1+i)\ln(1-i)$ using the Taylor series for the logarithm, and seeing that it equals the definition of $H_{1/4}$. Similarly, you can show that $H_{3/4}=\frac43-(1+i)\ln(1+i)-(2)\ln(2)-(1-i)\ln(1-i)$. Using Euler's formula, you can simplify those into what we have above.

Comment: I see. Would you mind showing me a "compressed" formula for the ***rational part*** of $$H_{(2n+1)/4} - H_{(2n-1)/4}$$

Answer (score 1):

The series could be defined by
\begin{align}
S_{m} = \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor m/4 \rfloor} \frac{1}{n}
\end{align}
where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ represents the largest integer of $x$. Now, consider the series
\begin{align}
H_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}
\end{align}
which are known as the Harmonic numbers. From this it is seen that the series in question is given by
\begin{align}
S_{m} = H_{\lfloor m/4 \rfloor}.
\end{align}
Alternatively, since $\psi(x+1) + \gamma = H_{x}$ then $S_{m} = \gamma + \psi(\frac{m}{4} + 1)$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\psi(x+1)$ is the digamma function.

Examples of values:
\begin{align}
S_{4} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor 4/4 \rfloor} \frac{1}{n} = 1 \\
S_{5} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor 5/4 \rfloor} \frac{1}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{1} \frac{1}{n} = 1.
\end{align}

Now, making use of 
$$J_{m} = \sum_{k=1}^{m/4} \frac{1}{k} = \gamma + \psi\left( \frac{m+4}{4} \right)$$
then
\begin{align}
J_{1} = \gamma + \psi\left( \frac{5}{4} \right) = 4 + \gamma + \psi\left( \frac{1}{4} \right)
\end{align}
It is known that $\psi\left(\frac{1}{4} \right) = - \gamma - \frac{\pi}{2} - 3\ln 2$ which leads to the result
\begin{align}
J_{1} = 4 - \frac{\pi}{2} - 3 \ln 2. 
\end{align}
For the case of $S_{3}$ it is seen that
\begin{align}
J_{3} &= \gamma + \psi\left( \frac{7}{4} \right) = 4 + \gamma + \psi\left( \frac{3}{4} \right) = 4 + \frac{\pi}{2} - 3 \ln 2. 
\end{align}

Comment: Can you show me how to calculate by hand $H_{m/4}$?

Comment: @mathlearner Honestly, the only way to get the _exact_ value is to add them one by one.

Comment: @columbus8myhw I mean that WolframAlpha outputs 4 - Pi/2 - Log[8] for HarmonicNumber[1/4], what are the steps that produce that?

Comment: @mathlearner Oh, I see what you mean. Well, $H_n$ is usually defined as $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$, but that definition is only valid for when $n$ is an integer. If $n$ is not an integer, we use the alternate definition:$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+n}\right)$$which is valid even when $n$ is not an integer. When you plug in $n=1/4$, however, you don't easily get the closed form. The way to get the closed form is complicated and won't fit in a comment.

Comment: @columbus8myhw If you've got some time, please write an answer.

Comment: @mathlearner, This link gives columbus8myhw's definition as well as a few recurrence relations and specific examples of fractional arguments to $H_x$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Special_values_for_fractional_arguments

Comment: @Leucippus: thanks for your answer. Could you just explain how you manipulate the polygamma function: for example, why psi(5/4)= 1/4 + 4?

Comment: @mathlearner use equation (21) from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html

Comment: @Leucippus: I see. And for example, how would you simplify `PSI[5/4 + n/2] - PSI[3/4 + n/2]` with `n` whatever integer using those?

Answer (score 0):

As @Leucippus describes in his answer, your series is really a harmonic number. There is no way to compute Harmonic numbers exactly but there is a nice approximation.

$$ H_n \approx \ln n + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{12n^2}$$

where $\gamma = 0.577215664901532860606512…$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'd appreciate some input on why my approximation is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum

It turns out your sum is

$$\psi(n/4+1)$$

where $\psi(x)$ is the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)